# Fastest way to find one leaf node that is a child of a particular node in an unsorted tree

Tags: data-structures, tree, path-finding, tree-traversal

I'm implementing a Digital Search Tree's 'delete' function.

What tree traversal algorithms should I use to find a leaf node that is a child of the deleted node?

The leaf not doesn't have to be the closest one or anything. Just a leaf.
Thank you

Comment: One way is to keep a list (or just one) leaf nodes around. When you insert, remember the last leaf. Otherwise, what is random? Just pick a random branch to go down. Or do you need the leaf to be uniformly random amongst all leafes?

Comment: I really don't get why you would need this though? To delete in a binary trie you need to traverse and delete the right leaf.

Comment: It's a digital search tree. To delete a node, you replace it with one of its leaf node.

Comment: I'm sorry for the wording. It's not really random. The leaf node has to be a child of the deleted node.